# how do i make a triangle using for loop in javascript which output matches the parameter content

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

```js
let printTriangle = (num) => {
 for ( let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
     num += '*';
  }
  num += "\n"
 }
}
console.log(printTriangle(5));
```

I have a simple question although i cannot manage to resolve this problem. Hope you can help, how i should fix my code to make output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: Step 1: Fix your syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let printTriangle = (num) => {
 let result = "";
 for ( let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
     result += '*';
  }
  result += "\n";
 }
 return result;
}
console.log(printTriangle(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are appending the desired string in num i.e a number resulting in wrong output.
You should rather initialize another variable inside your function and append * into it.
Also, you are not returning anything from this function that's why instead of some value *undefined* is getting logged.

```js
printTriangle = num => {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      result += "*";
    }
    result += "\n";
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(printTriangle(5));
```

There are many more ways to do this, you should try some other efficient ways also.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `repeat` method for this:

```js
function triangle(n) {
    let acc = "";
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        acc = `${acc}${"*".repeat(i)}\n`;
    }
  
    return acc;
}

console.log(triangle(5));
```